# How to parse(convert) the nested json array data into csv format in angularjs to Export the file xlsx format

Tags: angularjs

> Hi need to export the file xlsx format but i do have data in nested
>   json array format due to this im unable to fetch the data, can any one
>   help me in this since im trying to but not getting data properly

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="alasql.min.js"></script>
    <script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <html>
```

my script is

```
.fucntion($scope){
 $scope.inverters = [
  {
    "InvDetails": "UPS",
    "LstRecords": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 87,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
        "Lastreading": 5,
        "Readingby": 10
      },
      {
        "Id": 110,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 10,
        "Readingby": 92
      },
      {
        "Id": 111,
        "Invertor_Id": 1,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 92,
        "Readingby": 95
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "InvDetails": "Power Supply",

    "LstRecords": [
      {
        "Id": 2,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170214",
        "Lastreading": 0,
        "Readingby": 0
      },
      {
        "Id": 88,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170215",
        "Lastreading": 7,
        "Readingby": 13
      },
      {
        "Id": 109,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 13,
        "Readingby": 25
      },
      {
        "Id": 112,
        "Invertor_Id": 2,
        "Time_of_Reading": "20170216",
        "Lastreading": 25,
        "Readingby": 49
      }
    ]
  }
];
$scope.exportData = function () {
        var data="";
        $scope.headers=[];
         angular.forEach($scope.inverters,function(value,key){

        var we=value.InvDetails;
        $scope.headers.push(we);
        $scope.last=value.LstRecords;
        angular.forEach($scope.last,function(value,key){

            data={
                "Id": value.Id,
                "Invertor_Id": value.Invertor_Id,
                "Time_of_Reading":value.Time_of_Reading,
                "Lastreading": value.Lastreading,
                 "Readingby": value.Readingby
            };
        })
    })

         $scope.result=[];
         $scope.result0=[];

         $scope.result.push({
            "Invertor1":JSON.stringify(data)


         })

        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[result]);
    };
};
```

> can any one help me out how to export this one, if i need to split the
>   data since im getting data from API so if u split and export this it
>   would be helpfull form are any other solution is there means let me
>   know how to do. thanks in advance

Comment: <button ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>

Answer (score 0):

You can use SEARCH operator:

```
alasql('SEARCH / AS @r     \
        LstRecords / AS @l \
        RETURN(@r->InvDetails AS InvDetails,  \
               @l->Id AS Id,                  \
               @l->Invertor_Id AS Inventor_Id \
        ) \
        INTO XLSX("john.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',[result]);
```

Here AlaSQL walks over first array and saves current record into @r temporary varyable. Then it walks over nested LstRecords array and saves it to @l variable. RETURN clause generates the result object with all necessary fields.

Comment: but my data based has been created in mysql how can i use alasql here. can u please let me know bit more since im in confusion in that